# Getting GUID of recently inserted row

Tags: sql-server

Consider these two SQL Server tables

- `Person` (PersonId uniqueidentifier, PersonName varchar(20))
- `Hobby` (HobbyId int identity(1,1), PersonId uniqueidentifier, HobbyName)

My user interface takes the person name and list of hobbies as input. When user submits the form, I would like to insert appropriate records in the two tables. For e.g.

```
 insert into Person 
 values(NEWID(), 'John')
```

I wanted to know how can I get the value of this GUID so that I can do the insert into the `Hobby` table?

```
 insert into Hobby(PersonId, HobbyName) 
 values(WHAT???, 'Ping-pong')
```

There could be several John in the table. How can I get the GUID of this particular John?

Comment: Do you not have some sort of unique user key that you're passing to the stored procedure? e.g. User 123 clicks a button to add "ping-pong" hobby. When they click it, you pass in 123 and "ping-pong" to insert into the table. Otherwise, you'll have to do it in the same transaction using Scope_Identity()

Comment: Check about `@@IDENTITY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to pre-generate your `GUID` and use that in all your queries. It is the way I used in many of the places I required.

```
DECLARE @personId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @personId = NEWID()

insert into Person values(@personId , 'John')
insert into Hobby(PersonId, HobbyName) values(@personId, 'Ping-pong')
```

OR

You can have a temporary table to output the inserted value and use it in further queries *assuming the below statements execute only once in one single call*.

```
DECLARE @myIdentifier TABLE (
    InsertedGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

insert into Person 
output inserted.PersonId into @myIdentifier 
values(NEWID(), 'John')

insert into Hobby(PersonId, HobbyName) 
values(SELECT InsertedGuid FROM @myIdentifier, 'Ping-pong')
```

Comment: You can accept the answer in 44 seconds :) Thank you techspider

Comment: @bluepiranha - I can't accept the answer. Are you talking about the warning you received when you try to accept the answer? :)